# Why does CMD prompt TAB fail on filenames starting "!"?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

Why does CMD prompt TAB Automatic Completion fail on filenames starting "!"?

E.g.

[image]

press TAB, ENTER, gives

[image]

Worse:

[image]

gives

[image]

And

[image]

press TAB, gives just a beep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote <kbd>!</kbd> (opening quote is enough I believe). Straight from `help cmd`:

> The completion code deals correctly with file names that contain spaces
>   or other special characters by placing quotes around the matching path.
>   Also, if you back up, then invoke completion from within a line, the
>   text to the right of the cursor at the point completion was invoked is
>   discarded.
>
> The special characters that require quotes are:
>        <space>
>        &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~

I do not know exactly why (though most of them are cmd special chars), but obviously when **not** quoted, everything up to last such char (inclusive of it) is silently discarded (so the expansion matches **every file**).

Comment: "You need to quote ! ...  Straight from help cmd". Thanks, but that not what the help says. Help says "The completion code deals correctly ... by placing quotes around the matching path." My examples show it is failing to do so. "obviously when not quoted, they are silently discarded". Again, that's not what I see. See my last example.

Comment: @ChrisJJ The help explanation is bit unclear, but I understand it as: 1. **if** the match contains special characters, then returned file name will be quoted; 2. If you want put any of the following characters into your match pattern, you **must** quote it. Otherwise they are treated specially (as separators?). Try to enter `I want to search for!` and press Tab - it will cycle through **all** of your files. The logic is the same as when you want to search a file with a space in it (you also need a quote).

Comment: @ChrisJJ As for your last example, it does behave exactly as per my explanation - exclamation mark is not treated as part of pattern to match, and you do not have a file starting with Cur (without !)

Comment: changed answer to provide clearer explanation

Comment: "The help explanation is bit unclear" I think it is clear, and incorrect :)  Your new one is much better. Thanks. "As for your last example, it does behave exactly as per my explanation" Now I see that. Thanks for the correction.